# Which other literal values apart from NaN - are not equal to themselves

Tags: javascript, nan, triple-equals

It's a known fact in Js that the value NaN is not equal to itself

```
console.log(NaN === NaN)
// false
```

Which other Javascript literal values are not equal to themselves - or is NaN the only value??

I've already checked and found that undefined, null, Infinity, -Infinity are all equal to each other.

Comment: NaN should be unique in this regard: [Relational Expressions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch04s09.html)

Comment: Just `NaN`. Check [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465314/3082296)

Comment: This is not really specific to JavaScript, the IEEE 754 floating-point standard requires it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN